# How do I move Ubuntu 17.04 sidebar to the bottom-middle?

Tags: 17.04, dock

I searched for that, and all I could find was how to position the sidebar to the bottom and not to bottom-middle (i.e. like MacOS (bottom+centered)). How do I do that?

Comment: How is bottom middle diffrent to bottom? Moving it to the bottom makes it look like the Windows task bar, please clearly define bottom middle.

Comment: I.E. like MacOS (bottom+centered)

Comment: OK you can't do that with Unity, you want a dock like this one: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2015/01/how-to-add-a-dock-to-ubuntu-desktop-plank